# Jquery Datetimepicker inside angularjs directive

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datetimepicker

I created a angularjs directive to use the jquery datetimepicker. I am facing a peculiar issue. When I received the date from the database, the ng-model is showing the date as 2018-04-04T00:00:00 instead of the formatting 4-Apr-2018 12:00 AM which I set on the directive. 

I need to click the date control once to show the correct format. Please help to fix this problem.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" size="16" class="form-control" data-ng-model="inquiryInfo.DueDate" datetimepicker>
```

**JS**

```
demoApp.directive('datetimepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            angular.element(element).datetimepicker({
                format: "dd-M-yyyy H:ii P",
                autoclose: true,
                todaybtn: true,
                pickerposition: "bottom-left",
                minuteStep: 15,
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(date);
                    ctrl.$render();
                    scope.$apply();
               }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: is your question converting 2018-04-04T00:00:00 to 4-Apr-2018 12:00 AM?

Comment: After the value is binded from the database, I explicitly need to click the date control once to keep the correct format. Otherwise, it is showing the input control is showing the date as 2018-04-04T00:00:00. I want the date format to be 4-Apr-2018 12:00 AM without the clicking the date control

Comment: I found the solution. While bind the data back to the model, we have convert the date and keep it in the same format as specified in the directive.